# Store Express Session in Cookie

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, session-cookies

I have found various ways to store a session ID in a cookie for expressjs. What I actually want is to store all my session data in a cookie and not have to worry about a server-side session store.

Why? My session data is tiny and having a session store adds unnecessary complexity in my case.

Can this be done with express? Bonus points if you know how to encrypt it.

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I saw this, but the documentation is a little confusing. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Express cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) should do what you are wanting.

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieSession({
  secret: 'secret-key-you-don\'t-tell-the-client',
  signed: true,
}));
```

Using a combination of the `secret` key and ensuring your cookies are `signed` will prevent any cookie tampering by your end users.

Once setup you can then access the session using the `req.session` object in your controllers or use a compatible authentication module such as [Passport](http://passportjs.org/docs).